# Too much space in \begin{bfseries} as compared to {\bfseries ...}

Tags: fonts, spacing

When the following is compiled with pdflatex, there is more space between the part in bold in the first sentence than in the second sentence. Why is it so, and is there a way to have the first sentence with the correct spacing?

This problem was encountered while writing a program that generates latex code and I'd prefer to use the \begin{} ... \end{} structure for text formatting if possible.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

A sentence with
\begin{bfseries}
some words
\end{bfseries}
in  bold.

A sentence with  {\bfseries some words} in bold.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/107497

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you for the link, I'll read it to understand fully why dexteritas solution works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Description

- insert `%`, so no space is inserted at the end of the line (in code)
- or simply use `\textbf{...}`

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

A sentence with
\begin{bfseries}%
some words
\end{bfseries}%
in  bold.

A sentence with  {\bfseries some words} in bold.

A sentence with \textbf{some words} in  bold.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, the idea that `\begin{env}` is a wrapper for `\env` is a design mistake of LaTeX. Alas, it's not really possible to change this after 40 years.

There are *no* environments called `bfseries`, `itshape`, `large` or similar. One *can* use `\begin{bfseries}...\end{bfseries}`, but should know what actually happens.

In your input there is a space

- before `\begin{bfseries}`
- after `\begin{bfseries}`
- after `words`
- after `\end{bfseries}`

All of them come from the endlines. To the contrary, no spaces are added with

```
A sentence with {\bfseries some words} in bold.
```

but, of course, it's better to do

```
A sentence with \textbf{some words} in bold.
```

We can see why by typesetting all three versions in the same sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

A sentence with
\begin{bfseries}
some words
\end{bfseries}
in  bold.

A sentence with {\bfseries some words} in bold.

A sentence with \textbf{some words} in bold.

{\bfseries if} text

\textbf{if} text

\end{document}
```

Since the difference with `{\bfseries ...}` and `\textbf{...}` is not so evident from the example, I add two more tests. In the last one, you see that there's more space between “if” and ”text”, due to the italic correction that's added at font change.

[image]

The pseudoenvironment `bfseries` is safe if used *between* paragraphs. Otherwise you need to mask some of the endlines, limiting clarity of input.

On the other hand, a simple test shows that `\begin{large}...\end{large}` or similar is bad even between paragraphs. I use `scriptsize` in order to better show the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{scriptsize}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{scriptsize}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

{\scriptsize\lipsum[1][1-4]\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the second paragraph is typeset with the baseline distance pertaining to `\normalsize`, not to `\scriptsize`. The last paragraph is typeset correctly. Of course you might do

```
\begin{scriptsize}
\lipsum[1][1-4]\par
\end{scriptsize}
```

but, again, this requires thinking each time to what's needed.

Define your own environments correcting such bad behaviors, if you really want and avoid using declarations as environments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue because if you omit the `\par` in `{\scriptsize\lipsum[1][1-4]\par}`, the paragraph is also typeset with the wrong baseline distance, so the `{\scriptsize ...}` version is not better than the `begin ... end`.

Comment: @Gribouillis That's why I recommend defining your own environments and not rely on “naked” commands.