# when i exports a graph from geogebra then i got this axes without graph of function? why

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, geogebra

when i exports a graph from geogebra then i got this axes without graph of function? why
[image]

[image]

**code :**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{dcrutc}{rgb}{0.8627450980392157,0.0784313725490196,0.23529411764705882}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq,, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (-4.,-4.) grid (7.,6.);
\draw[->,ultra thick,color=black] (-4.,0.) -- (7.,0.);
\foreach \x in {-4.,-3.,-2.,-1.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick,color=black] (0.,-4.) -- (0.,6.);
\foreach \y in {-4.,-3.,-2.,-1.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-4.,-4.) rectangle (7.,6.);
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.0:0.15] plot[parametric] function{-27.69*t**(3.0)+0.0*t**(2.0)+13.89*t-3.0,-51.46*t**(3.0)+0.0*t**(2.0)-5.46*t+4.0};
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.15:0.25] plot[parametric] function{-35.69*t**(3.0)+3.62*t**(2.0)+13.35*t-2.97,77.51*t**(3.0)-58.34*t**(2.0)+3.33*t+3.56};
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.25:0.4] plot[parametric] function{62.34*t**(3.0)-68.76*t**(2.0)+31.16*t-4.43,-79.27*t**(3.0)+57.43*t**(2.0)-25.16*t+5.9};
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.4:0.55] plot[parametric] function{-10.1*t**(3.0)+17.48*t**(2.0)-3.07*t+0.09,410.98*t**(3.0)-526.32*t**(2.0)+206.53*t-24.76};
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.55:0.7] plot[parametric] function{-21.95*t**(3.0)+36.97*t**(2.0)-13.74*t+2.04,-397.63*t**(3.0)+802.26*t**(2.0)-521.1*t+108.08};
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.7:0.85] plot[parametric] function{97.91*t**(3.0)-214.2*t**(2.0)+161.69*t-38.8,12.51*t**(3.0)-57.12*t**(2.0)+79.14*t-31.67};
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.85:1.0] plot[parametric] function{-77.93*t**(3.0)+233.8*t**(2.0)-218.77*t+68.9,55.85*t**(3.0)-167.55*t**(2.0)+172.91*t-58.21};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=dcrutc] (-1.374,2.878) node {$Cf$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit :**

i go to install gunplot then compile it but i got same result.

[image]

[image]

the file f1.pgf-plot its ok but where mistake?

Comment: Because there are many mikstakes. Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `a97052aa-662f-46da-ba1b-6eab1e38a7a9.pgf-plot.table not found`. (for example).

Comment: @Sebastiano this code from geogebra ? How I have mistakes

Comment: Welcome. Did you follow the instructions of the comment in your picture? Is gnuplot installed? Is LaTeX run with shell escape active? Does gnuplot return a result?

Comment: Ellen have you tried to compile it?

Comment: yes i was compile it but i cant solve this !
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `f1.pgf-plot.table' not found.

Comment: Can you see edit ?

Comment: Remove all auxiliary files(only have your file (`f1.tex`) in the folder). Compile. Now does `f1.pgf-plot.table` exist? Carefully read all errors and warnings. Ask about these errors and warnings here, if you do not understand them. As it is now, it is not possible to help.

Comment: @hpekristiansen yes exist .... so where is the wrong ?

Comment: @Ellen Ellen, I post an answer, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the f1.tex, you have 7 functions without `id`, there will only be one table created by `Gnuplot` (the last). You therefore need an identifier per function.

`[parametric,id=pgf-plot1]` for the first function

`[parametric,id=pgf-plot2]` for the second function...

- After the first compilation there are only axes in the `pdf` and 7 warnings.

`f1.pgf-plot1.table not found`...

but 7 files were created in the folder.

[image]

- You must open each of these files with `gnuplot` to create the `.table` files

[image]

- A second compilation `pdflatex` and...

  ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \begin{document}
   \definecolor{dcrutc}{rgb}{0.8627450980392157,0.0784313725490196,0.23529411764705882}
   \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
   \draw [color=cqcqcq, xstep=1.0cm,ystep=1.0cm] (-4.,-4.) grid (7.,6.);
   \draw[->,ultra thick,color=black] (-4.,0.) -- (7.,0.);
   \foreach \x in {-4.,-3.,-2.,-1.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.}
   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
   \draw[->,ultra thick,color=black] (0.,-4.) -- (0.,6.);
   \foreach \y in {-4.,-3.,-2.,-1.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.}
   \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
   \draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
   \clip(-4.,-4.) rectangle (7.,6.);
   \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.0:0.15] plot[parametric,id=pgf-plot1] function{-27.69*t**(3.0)+0.0*t**(2.0)+13.89*t-3.0,-51.46*t**(3.0)+0.0*t**(2.0)-5.46*t+4.0};
   \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.15:0.25] plot[parametric,id=pgf-plot2] function{-35.69*t**(3.0)+3.62*t**(2.0)+13.35*t-2.97,77.51*t**(3.0)-58.34*t**(2.0)+3.33*t+3.56};
   \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.25:0.4] plot[parametric,id=pgf-plot3] function{62.34*t**(3.0)-68.76*t**(2.0)+31.16*t-4.43,-79.27*t**(3.0)+57.43*t**(2.0)-25.16*t+5.9};
   \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.4:0.55] plot[parametric,id=pgf-plot4] function{-10.1*t**(3.0)+17.48*t**(2.0)-3.07*t+0.09,410.98*t**(3.0)-526.32*t**(2.0)+206.53*t-24.76};
   \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.55:0.7] plot[parametric,id=pgf-plot5] function{-21.95*t**(3.0)+36.97*t**(2.0)-13.74*t+2.04,-397.63*t**(3.0)+802.26*t**(2.0)-521.1*t+108.08};
   \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.7:0.85] plot[parametric,id=pgf-plot6] function{97.91*t**(3.0)-214.2*t**(2.0)+161.69*t-38.8,12.51*t**(3.0)-57.12*t**(2.0)+79.14*t-31.67};
   \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=dcrutc, smooth,samples=100,domain=0.85:1.0] plot[parametric,id=pgf-plot7] function{-77.93*t**(3.0)+233.8*t**(2.0)-218.77*t+68.9,55.85*t**(3.0)-167.55*t**(2.0)+172.91*t-58.21};
   %\begin{scriptsize}%<--
   {\scriptsize
   \draw[color=dcrutc] (-1.374,2.878) node {$Cf$};
   %\end{scriptsize}
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Remark: Environment scriptsize does not exist. See this post [Too much space in \begin{bfseries} as compared to {\bfseries ...}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676524/too-much-space-in-beginbfseries-as-compared-to-bfseries)

Comment: You can also compile with the option `shell-escape` or `enable-write18` see the `pgfmanual` documentation section 22.6 Plotting a Function Using Gnuplot

Comment: I get it  .... Thanks sir+1!